# jQuery/PHP Posting multiple values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery UI to post multiple values in a dialog to a php script but I cannot seem to get them posted. I've seem examples using forms but I'm not using a form so they do not help either, really could do with some advice please

Comment: If you don't use forms, you should use QueryStrings

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug to see what the script is posting to the server and what the server is responding with?

Comment: yes, downloaded it but new to jquery so not a clue how to use it, not getting anything out of it

Comment: how about I send all the values to a hidden form then serialise it? would that work?

Comment: Please don't delete questions just because they've been answered; leave them so others can learn from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error: missing property id.

```
     $.post("addReading.php", {
                METER_READ: $(this).val(),
                DATE_TAKEN: $(this).val(),
                NOTES: NOTES.val() // I added NOTES:
            }, function (data) {
```

and your last `});` are too much (but that might be a copy/paste error).

Other than that I do not see why it does not work, but I cannot test it without a test case.

You should go on learning how to deal with firebug, though, because I'm sure it would have said you that the property id is missing (firebug is very good at detecting syntax errors, no need for humans in that case ;-) )