# Jquery post multiple vars to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to post multiple vars from jquery to php

```
<script>
//vote script
function vote(type){
$.post('vote.php', '{user_id: <?php echo $fb_userid;?>, page_name: <?php echo $get_image;?>, type: type}', function(data){
    $('#voteNumber').html(data);
    });
    }//end function
</script>
```

The above code is not working what is my problem ?

here is my php

```
if(isset($_POST['user_id']) && isset($_POST['page_name']) && isset($_POST['type'])){
        echo "done";
    }
```

Comment: Are you receiving an error? If so, it would be helpful to post what it is.

Comment: No error. here is my php

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852778/jquery-php-posting-multiple-values

Comment: I should get done back. but when I checking for the isset post. I am not getting anything back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
//vote script
function vote(type){
    $.post('vote.php', { user_id : '<?php echo $fb_userid;?>', page_name : '<?php echo $get_image;?>', type : type}, function(data){
        $('#voteNumber').html(data);
    });
}//end function
</script>
```

In your brackets, you had the entire thing surrounded by quotes. Only the value must be in quotes.

```
{ key : 'val', key2 : 'val2' }
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are not needed, this is javascript

you are passing an object directly as a parameter

```
<script>
//vote script
function vote(type){
    $.post('vote.php', {user_id: <?php echo $fb_userid;?>, page_name: '<?php echo $get_image;?>', type: type}, function(data){
        $('#voteNumber').html(data);
    });
}//end function
</script>
```

Comment: But quoting the value of `page_name` if it's a string `page_name: "<?php echo $get_image;?>"` should be done or you'll get a parsing error